# java.lang.StackOverflowError at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.l.l.a

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

```
 mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().addAll(drawCoordinates));
```

causes

```
 java.lang.StackOverflowError
                at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.l.l.a(Unknown Source)
                at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.l.l.a(Unknown Source)
                at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.l.l.a(Unknown Source)
```

with `drawCoordinates.size  > ~8000`

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Draw multiple polylines, each with a subset of the coordinates.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, while loading the 1500 points to draw polyline using method `PolylineOptions.addAll(points);`, please provide the solution to load large points to draw the polylines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Draw multiple polylines, each with a subset of the coordinates. – 
   CommonsWare
2. First create an empty polyline, after set coordinates (looks like it
   solves the problem)
       Polyline p = mMap.addPolyline .. ; pLines.get(i).setPoints(line);
3. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%E2%80%93Sutherland_algorithm
4. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm